# Как будет обработана конструкция if * and * and * or *

Tags: python, python-3.x, операторы, приоритет

Есть конструкция вида:

```
if a == 1 and b == 1 and c == 1 or c > 5:
    do_something()
```

Вопрос: как будет обработано условие `or`? мне нужно выполнить `do_something()` только если все 4 условия верны, но не интерпретирует ли python это условие

```
if a == 1 and b == 1 and c == 1 or c > 5
```

как два:
`a==1 and b==1 and c==1` и `c>5` и выполнит `do_something()`, если 1 из 2 условий верно?
ps `c==1 or c>5` - нужно сделать именно через `or`...

Comment: никак не обработается, тут ошибка в коде, путаешь оператор присваивания с оператором равенства

Comment: ошибка по запарке, я думаю очевидно что я имел ввиду

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "мне нужно выполнить do_something() только если все 4 условия верны:

```
if a==1 and b==1 and c==1 and c>5:
    do_something()
```

> "c==1 or c>5 - нужно сделать именно через or":

```
if a==1 and b==1 and (c==1 or c>5):
    do_something()
```

Приоритет операций:
https://wombat.org.ua/AByteOfPython/operators_and_expressions.html#id5

Answer (score 0):

Сначала выполняется логическое "И" (`and`), потом логическое "ИЛИ" (`or`). Таким образом:

1. `false and false and false or true` => `false and false or true` => `false or true` => `true`
2. `false and true and true or false` => `false and true or false` => `false or false` => `false`
3. `true and true and true or false` => `true and true or false` => `true or false` => `true`

То есть: чтобы всё условие вернуло `true`, у вас либо первые три операнда должны быть `true`, либо последний, либо все сразу.